# Are motionEvent coordinates device independent?

Tags: android

I'm using the OnSwipeTouchListener.java (https://gist.github.com/nesquena/ed58f34791da00da9751) in my Android code and I am wondering if the coordinates returned by MotionEvent when calling getX() or getY() are device independent.

Right now I'm using the listener on a view which is 280sp X 280sp in size. If I touch the top left of the view I get coordinates (0,0), on the bottom right, (560,560) (I don't really understand why the value is double the value of my view either).

If I run the app on a different device will I still get the same values or do they vary from device to device?

If the coordinates depend on the device how can I make the detection work across different devices?

Comment: I just managed to hook up my tablet to Android Studio as well. There I get a value of (275,275). So I guess I just answered my question if there is a difference on different devices. - There is. So the question that remains is how to handle it with the code.By the way the view I assigned the listener to is a linear layout.

Comment: It seems that my phone has a density of 320. Therefore the view which I specified with 280sp x 280sp is shown with 560px x 560px. Therefore the touch feedback is accordingly. My tablet has a density of 160. Therefore the view is shown with 280px x 280px and the touch values are according as well. I don't understand it 100% yet but that's what it is.

Comment: How have you solved your issue?